# Unwanted white spaces resulting into distorted column

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, csv

I am trying to import a list of chemicals from a txt file which is spaced (not tabbed).

[image]

```
NO FORMULA NAME CAS No A B C D TMIN TMAX code ngas@TMIN ngas@25 C ngas@TMAX
1 CBrClF2 bromochlorodifluoromethane 353-59-3 -0.0799 4.9660E-01 -6.3021E-05 -9.0961E-09 200 1500 2 96.65 142.14 572.33
2 CBrCl2F bromodichlorofluoromethane 353-58-2 4.0684 4.1343E-01 1.6576E-05 -3.4388E-08 200 1500 2 87.14 127.90 545.46
3 CBrCl3 bromotrichloromethane 75-62-7 7.3767 3.5056E-01 6.9163E-05 -4.9571E-08 200 1500 2 79.86 116.73 521.53
4 CBrF3 bromotrifluoromethane 75-63-8 -9.5253 6.5020E-01 -3.4459E-04 1.0987E-07 230 1500 1,2 123.13 156.61 561.26
5 CBr2F2 dibromodifluoromethane 75-61-6 2.8167 4.9405E-01 -1.2627E-05 -2.8629E-08 200 1500 2 100.89 148.24 618.87
6 CBr4 carbon tetrabromide 558-13-4 10.6812 3.2869E-01 1.0739E-04 -6.0788E-08 200 1500 2 80.23 116.62 540.18
7 CClF3 chlorotrifluoromethane 75-72-9 13.8075 4.7487E-01 -1.3368E-04 2.2485E-08 230 1500 1,2 116.23 144.10 501.22
8 CClN cyanogen chloride 506-77-4 0.8665 3.6619E-01 -2.9975E-05 -1.3191E-08 200 1500 2 72.80 107.03 438.19
```

When I import with pandas

```
df = pd.read_csv('trial1.txt', sep='\s')
```

I get:

[image]

For first 5 compounds (index 0-4) name is correctly in `Name` column but for 6th (index 5) and 8th (index 7) compounds - their name is divided because of *space* and it goes to `CAS`. Causing `CAS` column value to go under `No` column and values and so on subsequently.

Is there a way to eliminate this issue ? Thank you

Comment: can u post the text file as text instead of image pls..

Comment: Regular expressions can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

You basically have to strip out the spaces between words in the name column. So here I first read the file and then strip out the spaces in the NAME column using `re.sub`.

In this code, I am assuming that words are separated by atleast 5 letters on either sides. You can change that number  `{5}` as you deem fit.

```
import re
with open('trial1.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
l = [re.sub(r"([a-z]{5,})\s([a-z]{5,})", r"\1\2", line) for line in lines] 
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('\n'.join(l)), delim_whitespace=True)
```

Prints:

```
NO  FORMULA NAME                        CAS          No     A       B            C              D       TMIN    TMAX    code    ngas@TMIN   ngas@25 C.1 ngas@TMAX
1   CBrClF2 bromochlorodifluoromethane  353-59-3    -0.0799 0.49660 -0.000063   -9.096100e-09   200     1500    2       96.65   142.14      572.33  NaN NaN
2   CBrCl2F bromodichlorofluoromethane  353-58-2    4.0684  0.41343  0.000017   -3.438800e-08   200     1500    2       87.14   127.90      545.46  NaN NaN
3   CBrCl3  bromotrichloromethane       75-62-7     7.3767  0.35056  0.000069   -4.957100e-08   200     1500    2       79.86   116.73      521.53  NaN NaN
4   CBrF3   bromotrifluoromethane       75-63-8     -9.5253 0.65020 -0.000345    1.098700e-07   230     1500    1,2     123.13  156.61      561.26  NaN NaN
5   CBr2F2  dibromodifluoromethane      75-61-6     2.8167  0.49405 -0.000013   -2.862900e-08   200     1500    2       100.89  148.24      618.87  NaN NaN
6   CBr4    carbontetrabromide          558-13-4    10.6812 0.32869  0.000107   -6.078800e-08   200     1500    2       80.23   116.62      540.18  NaN NaN
7   CClF3   chlorotrifluoromethane      75-72-9     13.8075 0.47487 -0.000134    2.248500e-08   230     1500    1,2     116.23  144.10      501.22  NaN NaN
8   CClN    cyanogenchloride            506-77-4    0.8665  0.36619 -0.000030   -1.319100e-08   200     1500    2       72.80   107.03      438.19  NaN NaN
```

Comment: Hi @sharathnatraj , Thanks a lot for the answer. In my spyder, `df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('\n'.join(l)), delim_whitespace=True)` isn't working. The error is the following: `NameError: name 'io' is not defined`. What am I missing?

Comment: can u try `import io`

Comment: Big thanks.. works exactly the way I wanted. :D

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you put some work on the 'trial1.txt' file before loading it to df. The following code will result to what you finally want to get:

```
with open ('trial1.txt') as f:
    l=f.readlines()

l=[i.split() for i in l]
target=len(l[1])
for i in range(1,len(l)):
    if len(l[i])>target:
        l[i][2]=l[i][2]+' '+l[i][3]
        l[i].pop(3)
l=['#'.join(k) for k in l] #supposing that there is no '#' in your entire file, otherwise use some other rare symbol that doesn't eist in your file
l=[i+'\n' for i in l]
 
with open ('trial2.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(l)

df = pd.read_csv('trial2.txt', sep='#', index_col=0)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. When I am running your code `TypeError: writelines() takes exactly one argument (0 given)`. So not sure how to proceed there. Could you please help out there?

Comment: With the updated code, I am still not getting the desired result. What happening is, instead of getting compound as a separate line, I am getting that values between `#` as new column names

Comment: Can you please paste a sample of the df that is created with my solution?

Comment: below is the result of `df.columns` -->

Index(['NO', 'FORMULA', 'NAME', 'CAS', 'No', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'TMIN',
       ...
       '0.8665', '3.6619E-01', '-2.9975E-05', '-1.3191E-08', '200.5', '1500.7',
       '2.5', '72.80', '107.03', '438.19'],

values are becoming column names.

Comment: What is the result of len(l)? Is it 1?

Comment: No, len(l) is 9. I think something needs to be changed in `with open ('trial2.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(l)` but not sure what. Thanks

Comment: I did some changes in the code, please try again. The problem was that is should be `l=[['#'.join(k)] for k in l]` instead of `l=['#'.join(k) for k in l]`

Comment: @ IoaTzimas : Thanks for all the help. Now the issue is with the `with open ('trial2.txt', 'w') as f:
f.writelines(l)`. trial2.txt is empty. Error is: `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list`

Comment: Hi @pukumarathe i have updated my answer, please check again, it should work propery now

Comment: Thanks.. Now it works indeed for this data set. However, if I apply the same code for the sample data set of  the other question (which is different than this one), I get `ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 16 fields in line 43, saw 17`. Question: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65456221/variable-number-of-unwanted-white-spaces-resulting-into-distorted-column`

Comment: Just play with the target and with the code in case that some cells are split into more than 2 parts. See my explanation in your new question. Let's discuss it there
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65456221/variable-number-of-unwanted-white-spaces-resulting-into-distorted-column/65456270?noredirect=1#comment115723498_65456270)